# Responsive li nav background-color is only behind words

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists, background-color

I am writing a responsive navigation, based on a HTML list.

The goal is a nav, which always fills out 100% width of the header, with equally wide li elements. The background color only shows up behind the words. It does not fill out the entire li element, like it should.

Here the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#" >About Us</a></li>
        <li class="sports"><a href="#" >Sports</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#" >News & Events</a></li>
        <li class="vols"><a href="#" >Volunteer</a>/li>
        <li class="donate"><a href="#" >Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here the CSS:

```
.mainheader nav {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 10%;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0%;
}
.mainheader nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 14.28%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center
}

.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: 0 auto;
    padding: 17.5px 0px 17.5px 0px;
    height: 40px
}

.mainheader nav .about a:link, .mainheader nav .about a:visited {
    background-color: #7ab503; /* color not hover */
    text-shadow: none;
}
.mainheader nav .about a:visited, .mainheader nav .about a:hover {
    background-color: #bffc43; /* color hover */
}

/* all the other li elements have the same css structure as the .about one! */
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. you didn't provide background for the `li`s, but just for the `a`s; 2. please fill a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ^^.

Comment: What the heck is `text-align: 0 auto;`? I guess you probably mean `margin: 0 auto;`. What are `.5px` values for? Doesn't make sense. In case of `0` values for properties, like in `padding: 0%` it's useful, to write those values without measuring unit.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the CSS flexbox?

```
    .mainheader nav ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0%;
        background: #7ab503;
    }

    .mainheader nav ul li {
        display: block;
        flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
        float:left;
        display: inline;
        width: 14.28%;
        padding: 0% ;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #7ab503;
    }
```

and then you can fiddle with the background color

Answer (score 0):

The code was pretty messy so I cleaned it up a little on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNLKx/3/)

HTML:

```
<header class="mainheader">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#" >About Us</a></li>
        <li class="sports"><a href="#" >Sports</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#" >News & Events</a></li>
        <li class="vols"><a href="#" >Volunteer</a></li>
        <li class="donate"><a href="#" >Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.mainheader nav {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align:center;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
.mainheader nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;

}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:14.28%;
}

.mainheader nav a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 20px
    font-size: 20px;
}

.mainheader nav .about a {
    background-color: #7ab503; /* color not hover */
    text-shadow: none;
}
.mainheader nav .about a:visited, .mainheader nav .about a:hover {
    background-color: #bffc43; /* color hover */
}
```

Currently all the nav have centered and flexible buttons without floating messing code and no flex box which is not compatible with IE8